# How I can sync without attaching based on a specific column data in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

There is data get from a User, and I want to sync them based on the `code`:

the `cart_variation` table has these columns:

```
cart_id, variation_id, code, title, type
```

I want to sync without detaching data based on the `code`. if `code` exists update other data like type, title else insert. I mean among data as :

here is some code but don't work properly:

```
$this->instance()->variations()->syncWithoutDetaching([$variation->id =>
 [$code => ['title' => $title, 'type' => $type]],
],
```

OR

this code don't sync code and I make many entries with same code

```
DB::table('cart_variation')
  ->updateOrInsert(
   ['cart_id' => $this->cart->id, 'variation_id' => $variation->id, 'code' => $code],
   ['title' => $title, 'type' => $type]
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('cart_variation')
  ->updateOrInsert(
   ['code' => $code],
   ['title' => $title, 'type' => $type, 'cart_id' => $this->cart->id, 'variation_id' => $variation->id]
            );
```

Same behaviour happens with the Eloquent way of `updateOrCreate`, a similar example will be:

```
CartsModel::updateOrCreate(
   ['code' => $code],
   ['title' => $title, 'type' => $type, 'cart_id' => $this->cart->id, 'variation_id' => $variation->id]
            );
```

For `updateOrInsert` & `updateOrCreate` the first array is the comparison array.

So basically the above code will check if the `$code` you are providing exists:

- if the case is yes it will update the fields `title,type,cart_id,variation_id`
- otherwise will create a new record

Comment: Thank you worked with updateOrInsert function.

Comment: The difference between updateOrCreate and updateOrInsert is that updateOrCreate is part of the Eloquent and updateOrInsert is part of Query, but they do the same thing and work the same way. Glad i helped you in your question.